# Dynamical translation of HTML page with Google API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically translate context of my HTML page using Google API and the following code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var allTextValues = [];
    var translatedValues = [];
    var wholeDoc = $("html");
    // poziv fje za prolaz tagova
    iterateTags(wholeDoc);
    alert(allTextValues);
    iterateThroughArray()
        .then(function (translations) {
            alert(translations);
            for (let i = 0; i < translations.length; i++) {
                console.log(allTextValues[i] + " translated to " + translations[i]);
                translatedValues.push(translations[i]);
            }
            iterateAndRewrite(wholeDoc);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });    
        
    /**
     * funkcija kojom se ponovo prolazi citava stranica i upisuju se prevedene reci u nju
     */
    let counter = 0;
    function iterateAndRewrite(element) {
        element.contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && $(this).text().trim() !== "") {
                $(this).text(translatedValues[counter++]);
            } else if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                iterateAndRewrite($(this));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * prolazi ceo html kroz inner vrednosti tagova
     * @param {html tag} element 
    */
    function iterateTags(element) {
        element.contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && $(this).text().trim() !== "") {
                allTextValues.push($(this).text());
            } else if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                iterateTags($(this));
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * prolazi kroz niz i u slucaju da polje sadrzi cirilicne karaktere prevodi ga i upisuje nazad
     */
    function iterateThroughArray() {
        var translationPromises = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < allTextValues.length; i++) {
            let translationPromise = translate(allTextValues[i], "sr", "en");
            translationPromises.push(translationPromise);
        }
        return Promise.all(translationPromises);
    }


    /**
     * prosledjeni tekst prevodi sa jezika sourceLang na jezik targetlang
     * @param {String} sourceText 
     * @param {String} sourceLang 
     * @param {String} targetLang 
     */
    function translate(sourceText, sourceLang, targetLang) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);

            $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
                var translation = data[0][0][0];
                resolve(translation);
            }).fail(function (error) {
                reject(error);
            });
        });

    }
});
```

All translations right, but I do not know why in iterateAndRewrite function text does not change. I included all needed JQuery libraries and  linked script file properly (tested it with alert). Translations are correct, i checked it in console so I only can not rewrite content of inner html tags.